# nodejs/mongoose: What is wrong with my chained .then() calls

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My code below is attempting to:

1. Create an instance of the `User` model
2. Find the instance in the `Subscriber` model with the same email address as the newly created user
3. Associate the new user's `subscribedAccount` property to the `Subscriber` instance found by the `findOne` query on the `user.email`

Code:

```
// Check that I have a subscriber with email 'test@test.com'
Subscriber.findOne({email:'test@test.com'})
          .then(d => console.log(`\nResult of check for a subscriber with email test@test.com:\n ${d}`));

User.create({name: {first: 'test first', last: 'test last'}, email: 'test@test.com', password: 'pass123'})
.then(u => {
  user = u;
  // Check that user.email contains 'test@test.com'
  console.log(`\nCreated user's email address: ${user.email}\n`);
  Subscriber.findOne({email: user.email});
})
.then(s => {
  console.log(`\nAnything found by findOne and passed to this .then()?: ${s}`);
  user.subscribedAccount = s;
  user.save();
})
.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

Console results:

> Server running at http://localhost:3000 Successfully connected with
>   Mongoose!
>
> Result of check for a subscriber with email test@test.com:
>   { groups:
>   [],   _id: 5aa422736518f30fbc0f77e2,   name: 'test name',   email:
>   'test@test.com',   zipCode: 11111,   __v: 0 }
>
> Created user's email address: test@test.com
>
> Anything found by findOne and passed to this .then()?: undefined

Why is `Subscriber.findOne` returning `undefined`? Is that what is actually happening or is it something else I'm missing?

Here are my model definitions for `User` and `Subscriber`. Let me know if you need to see anything else from the application to tell what is going on.

`User`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new Schema( {
  name: {
    first: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    last: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    }
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true
  },
  zipCode: {
    type: Number,
    min: [ 10000, 'Zip code too short' ],
    max: 99999
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  courses: [ {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Course'
  } ],
  subscribedAccount: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Subscriber'
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
} );

userSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function() {
  return `${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}`;

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

`Subscriber`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let subscriberSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true
  },
  zipCode: {
    type: Number,
    min: [10000, 'Zip Code too short'],
    max: 99999
  },
  groups: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group'}]
});

subscriberSchema.methods.getInfo = function() {
  return `Name: ${this.name} Email: ${this.email} Zip Code: ${this.zipCode}`;
}
subscriberSchema.methods.findLocalSubscribers = function() {
  return this.model('Subscriber')
             .find({zipCode: this.zipCode})
             .exec();
}

//model.exports = mongoose.model('Subcriber', subscriberSchema);

var Subscriber = exports.Subscriber = mongoose.model('Subscriber', subscriberSchema);
```

Comment: You need to return it. In the first then return the last expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have done like this

```
// Check that I have a subscriber with email 'test@test.com'
    Subscriber.findOne({email:'test@test.com'})
              .then(d => console.log(`\nResult of check for a subscriber with email test@test.com:\n ${d}`));

    User.create({name: {first: 'test first', last: 'test last'}, email: 'test@test.com', password: 'pass123'})
    .then(u => {
      user = u;
      // Check that user.email contains 'test@test.com'
      console.log(`\nCreated user's email address: ${user.email}\n`);
      Subscriber.findOne({email: user.email});


      console.log(`\nAnything found by findOne and passed to this .then()?: ${s}`);
      user.subscribedAccount = s;
      user.save()
      .then(s => {
            //user has been updated
        })
      .catch(err => {
         res.status(err).json(err);
         })

      })
       })
     . catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```